# Maxscript syntax highlights for Sublime?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, maxscript

I know there currently isn't a  Maxscript syntax definition for SublimeText2, but is it possible to easily either convert an existing syntax set from say Notepad++ or Textpad or create one (more of a daunting prospect as I wouldn't know where to begin)?

Comment: I'd like to know too, what I do know for now is that the Lua syntax matches 'best'.

Comment: For Maxscript I ended up using the default maxscript editor, only I changed the MAXscript.properties file to match the colour scheme I was after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created one today:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zj5egnr0a74ldui/MaxScript.zip

I'm new to language definition so there's still a few loose ends here and there, but it does the job so far. If you have any issues, suggestions or fixes, please let me know.

I haven't had a chance yet to upload it to GitHub for Package Control, but I'll get to that one day. Until then, just use the download link above and place the file in your Package dir, in a directory called /MaxScript.

Enjoy!

Edit 12/10/2013: Updated the link, it works again now.

Comment: Rogier, just installed it and so far it looks good. No more MaxEditor :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! As I was using it yesterday, I still discovered a few rough edges. Particularly function calls need some work, and I'd like to find a proper way to differentiate brackets visually. Also, the word definitions I'm using are from 2006, so they're probably a bit outdated. But I'm happy with how it turned out for a first pass. Please comment here if you find any issues or have suggestions!

Comment: I've just done a [quick comparison](http://dropcanvas.com/gevxu) with a bit of code from [here](http://www.chrisevans3d.com/pub_blog/?p=7) which might help. The top part is using the max Editor, the bottom is Sublime Text 2

Comment: Thanks, Ghoul Fool. I noticed that the SublimeText in the screenshot has its language set to Lua (at the bottom right), which could by caused by my file types not being set up correctly. Would you mind switching it to MaxScript and seeing if it's any better?

Comment: Oops! Missed that. I've updated the [image](http://dropcanvas.com/2ktcq) with the language set to Maxscript.

Comment: The dropbox file no longer exists?

Comment: @RogierVanEtten Can you re-upload you language definition?